# Typescript named arg for object

Tags: typescript

How do I have named arg be object without it breaking?

```
type CellRenderer = ({
  rowData: { [key: string]: any },
}) => JSX.Element;
```

Comment: Could you please provide expected type? Don't understand the question

Comment: Presumably you either want `(rowdata: { [key: string]: any }) => JSX.Element` or `(arg: { rowData: { [key: string]: any } }) => JSX.Element` but without a [mcve] it's impossible to say for sure.  Please consider reviewing the guidelines for [ask], and good luck!